# Finding the week number from a date in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, vb.net

I want to compare 2 dates and check that they are in the same week. Is there a way to find the week number of each date and compare them, or an alternative function to compare the dates and see if they're in the same week?
Thank you :)))))))))))))))))

Comment: VBA is not the same as VB.net

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the vba Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) - use something like `Format(DateVariable, "ww")` to get week number of a date.

Answer (score 0):

in VBA, use `DateDiff` which returns 0 (zero) for a match:

```
WeekMatch = Not CBool(DateDiff("ww", Date1, Date2, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem))
```